# How to make output to a single line from multi line. Can we do it using generators as well?

Tags: python, scripting

Please have a look to the below output :-

```
Software_Engineer: 
Networking
Software_Engineering
Computer_Graphics
Development
Design

Mechanical_Engineer:
Automata
(There is a new line character here)
```

I want output should be as :-

```
Software_Engineer: Networking Software_Engineering Computer_Graphics Development Design

Mechanical_Engineer: Automata
```

I wrote below code in python as of now :-

```
with open("split_module.txt") as f:
    all_lines = f.readlines()
    keys_col1 = []
    values_col2 = []
    for ids, values in enumerate(all_lines):
        if ":" in all_lines[ids] and all_lines[ids+1] != "\n":
            keys_col1.append(values.strip())
            for value in keys_col1:
                print(value)
```

I am now getting output as :-

```
Software_Engineer:
Software_Engineer:
Mechanical_Engineer:
```

Here, Why "Software_Engineer:" is repeating two times and how can I able to get output as :-

```
Software_Engineer: Networking Software_Engineering Computer_Graphics Development Design

Mechanical_Engineer: Automata
```

Please suggest as I am new to Python.... Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
fle=open("C:\Python27\projects\infile.txt")
fle2=open("C:\Python27\projects\outfile.txt",'w')
lst=fle.readlines()
for i in lst:
    i=i.strip()
    if i.endswith(':'):
        fle2.write("\n")
        fle2.write(i)
    else:
        fle2.write(i)
        fle2.write(" ")
fle.close()
fle2.close()
```

COntent of outflie.txt

```
Software_Engineer:Networking Software_Engineering Computer_Graphics Development Design  
Mechanical_Engineer:Automata
```

Comment: Good to hear :-) please follow [link] https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers [link] to mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty

```
def f1(txt):
     buffer = ""
     for ee in txt.splitlines():
         if ee.endswith(':'):
             if buffer:
                 yield buffer.strip()
             buffer = ""
         buffer += ee + " "
     yield buffer.strip()
```

then you can for

```
for i in f1(txt):
    print(i)
```

you would use the same idea to read the data from file i wrote is as if this was all in string

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired output by :-

```
fle=open("C:\Python27\projects\infile.txt")
fle2=open("C:\Python27\projects\outfile.txt",'w')
lst=fle.readlines()
for i in lst:
    i=i.strip()
    if i.endswith(':'):
        fle2.write("\n")
        fle2.write(i)
    else:
        fle2.write(i)
        fle2.write(" ")
fle.close()
fle2.close()
```

Thanks for help..